# Identity Server 4 after Redirect to signin-oidc using reverseProxy displays "message.State is null or empty."

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, reverse-proxy, identityserver4, openid-connect

I keep receiving an error trying to authenticate using IdentityServer4.

IS4: http://dev.com/

Client: http://dev.com/Account/

Path:

1) By accessing http://dev.com/Account/security I am redirected to http://dev.com/login.

2) After logging in, I am redirected to http://dev.com/Account/signin-oidc
and I get Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.

My IS4 configuration:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                        {

                            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                            options.IssuerUri = Configuration.GetIssuerUri();
                            options.PublicOrigin = Configuration.GetPublicOrigin();
                            options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Login/login";
                            options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Login/logout";
                        })
                    .AddSigningCredential(Configuration.GetSigningCertificate())
                    .AddValidationKey(Configuration.GetValidationKeyCertificate())
                    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
                    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
                    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

Client in IS4 configuration:

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientName = "Aplikacja do zarządzania kontem",
                    ClientId = "Account",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    RequirePkce = true,

                    // where to redirect to after login
                    RedirectUris = { "http://dev.com/Account/signin-oidc" }, 

                    // where to redirect to after logout
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { " http://dev.com/Account/signout-callback-oidc" }, 

                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                      ...
                    },

                    AllowOfflineAccess = true
                },
```

Client startup:

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql("XXX"));

            services.AddXServices(Configuration);
            services.AddXValidators();
            services.AddXMappers();
            services.AddXRepositories();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = true;

            services.AddXentication(options =>
                {

                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Xority = " http://dev.com/"; 
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ClientId = "Account";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code";
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;
                    options.CallbackPath = "/Account/signin-oidc";

                    ......

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                });


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            var fordwardedHeaderOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
            };

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(fordwardedHeaderOptions);
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    var prefix = Configuration.GetUrlPrefix();
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        pattern: prefix + "{controller=Test}/{action=Index}")
                             .RequireHost(Configuration.GetRequiredHosts()).RequireAuthorization();

                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                            defaults: new { controller = "security" },
                            name: "security",
                            pattern: prefix + "security/{action=security}")
                        .RequireHost(Configuration.GetRequiredHosts()).RequireAuthorization();
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "error",
                        pattern: prefix + "Error/",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error" })
                             .RequireHost(Configuration.GetRequiredHosts());
                });
        }
```

Locally without reversproxy works

Comment: Have you try to get the user with this method this.userManager.getUser() just to make sure you have the user data in the client? what method of the oidc library do you call when you get inside the redirect page?

Comment: 1) I have users on the Identity Server side, on the client side, when I work on localhost, I normally get a user sub(id).
2) I don't quite understand what you mean